# Microsoft Graph API: Using Graph Explorer to do sample query of "my mail" and receive error 403

Tags: email, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Graph Explorer to execute the sample query "my mail", which is just "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages", however I'm receiving the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "71227405-861e-493c-83d6-162f4434aa4c",
            "date": "2019-06-14T16:06:41"
        }
    }
}
```

Per the Graph API "get messages" article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) the only permission I need is "Mail.Read".

I cant post images (new account) but here's a copy paste from the modify permissions screen:

```
Mail.Read Consented
Mail.Read.Shared Consented
Mail.ReadBasic Consented
Mail.ReadWrite Consented
Mail.ReadWrite.Shared Consented
Mail.Send Consented
Mail.Send.Shared Consented
MailboxSettings.ReadWrite Consented
```

The other sample queries of "my profile" and "items trending around me" work.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Changed permissions, searched on stackoverflow for similar issues, and changed the GET query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try removing the `Mail.ReadBasic` permission? I think Exchange is throwing an access denied error because of conflicting permissions.

Edit: I believe the `Mail.ReadBasic` scope is only meant to be used in /beta version. If you're using v1.0 make sure to not consent to it. If you do consent, you can revoke the app (be careful with this though if your app isn't just for dev purposes!)

Comment: I can't remove that one; in fact I can't remove any consented scopes. They are grayed out and a red circle appears when I hover over the checkbox to add/remove the scope.

Comment: In the Explorer I can do CreateMessage and then SendMessage, but if I try to CreateReply with the ID from CreateMessage I get this 404:

"The specified object was not found in the store. The process failed to get the correct properties.

I wonder if that's because I can't read my own mail properly. It can't reply to what it can't locate?

Comment: Finally figured it out.

I had to go to MyApps, click on Outlook, click on my name in the upper-right and select My Account, from the left-side menu click on App Permissions, find Graph Explorer, and hit revoke. What a disaster of a workflow.

Comment: I'm glad you figured out how to get past this issue. I've passed this feedback to the Exchange team